# import a web project using ant build file

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, import

I have a web project from `TrortoiseSVN`. When I import this project into `workspace` using ANT `build.xml` it become a simple java project. It is not recognize the **web-inf** and web root folder.
How I import this project into `workspace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an empty project like you want, and then copy the file to the project which you created. And then enter "F5" to see it or not success!

Comment: there are lot of bug.In this method.I faced

Answer (score 1):

For Juno, do File->New->Other, then select File -> New -> Other, and at the New dialog, select Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile

Comment: i did this but it becomes a java project. i've web project.\

Answer (score 1):

try importing the project in a different way, maybe import it as an existing project into eclipse